# How to apply patch to a buffer in place?

Tags: vimdiff

I want to use `yapf` to reformat parts of python buffers.

Yapf can take input from stdin `yapf -l 30-40`. This would produce output that is the whole buffer but with lines 30-40 reformatted. I can then generate diff between the `file.py` as it is in vim buffer and yapf output. But I don't know how to apply this diff to a current buffer inside of `formatexpr`.

Comment: have you checked the `:diffpatch` command?

Comment: I did. That's why I'm asking how to make it work inplace instead of creating new buffer with patched content.

Comment: Well, you did not mention it in your question and it should be possible to filter the file through a program, that patches its input and produces the desired output. Second, you might want to evaluate the 'patchexpr' option, that might also work.

Comment: @Christian Brabandt Do you know such program? Because I don't and I'm not inclined to write one. And how `patchexpr` might work?

Comment: sure, `patch` :) running `diff -N |patch ` works just fine. Besides, you can also throw some vimscript at the problem, temporarily save the buffer, apply the patch and reload the file from the disk

Comment: Chris, I think you don't understand what I want because I've been too specific in my question. Reloading file from disk would result in the same problem @Rich answer have. Wrong undo history and cursor jumps. I want to be able to reformat parts of files, like a paragraph with correct undo history without my cursor jumping on undo etc. Am I clear now? I don't think your suggestions will achieve this.

Comment: Yeah, I might have totally misunderstood you. However, reloading a file, does usually store the undo information. I fail to see the problem here. Regarding the cursor positioning, you can always throw a bit of Vimscript at this problem

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Ok, I've tried reloading a file and it also has problems. It works fine first time, but then it gives me warning `file has changed and the buffer has changed. The only thing that works is saving a buffer and modifying a file with `yapf` in place, which is ugly. Do you know the way without creating any temporary files and other hacks? `:%!yapf -l 30-40` is doing almost what I want. Why my cursor jumps if I change the buffer, but not when I change the file? Maybe there is some way of changing that behaviour?

Comment: If you know what you are doing, you can silence that message by setting the 'buftype' option to a non-empty value

Comment: BTW: You can always wrap your changes into a `winsaveview()`/`winrestview()` function, so the cursor and viewport does not change

Comment: I know `winsaveview`, thanks. The problem is that when undoing changes done with `%!yapf` cursor jumps to first line. And why is vim shows me this message I told earlier?

Comment: because that is a safety message when the buffer and the file changes? That's why you can change the `buftype` option as said earlier. It is totally expected that the cursor jumps on undo. That is how undo works.

Answer (score 2):

Vim provides a `filter` feature aimed at this sort of problem. This allows you to pass content from Vim into an external tool, and then replace that content with the tool's output.

The documentation can be found at `:help filter`, but to replace the entire contents of your file with the output of your `yapf` command you can use the command:

```
:%!yapf -l 30-40
```

For commands that don't require the entire content of the buffer as input, you can use a range with a filter (See `:help :range!`). e.g.:

```
:30,40!yapf
```

Comment: Unfortunately yapf does need the whole content.

Comment: How about `%!yapf -l 30-40` then?

Comment: I've tried that. It makes vim think that last change was to change the whole buffer. Which moves the cursor and is inconvenient.

Comment: First off all cursor still jumps around, second I repeat it makes vim think that I've changed the whole buffer, so when I undo cursor jumps to the first line.

Comment: @user1685095 Okay. I'm going to leave my answer up anyway, in case it helps other people in the future that don't have precisely the same requirements as you.

Comment: @user1685095 Have you found a way to fix this?  I'm trying to get around the exact same issue.

Comment: @CălinCruceru with yapf? https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server/pull/358
I'm not even using python at daily job anymore and switch to using microsoft language server via coc.nvim. I haven't had time to properly configure yapf for it, but as you can see from my pull request it's completely possible to use yapf with language server and not change the whole document to format it.